# Connection to Synapse Workspace with Private End Points. 403 error

Tags: endpoint, azure-synapse

I have set up a  Synapse workspace to use a managed VNet with data exfilteration. This works ok when I allow Public Access.[image: Overview Settings]
However when I connect I get a 403 error when I disable public access.
[image: What I get when connecting 403]

I have looked at using a [private link hub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/security/synapse-private-link-hubs) but this has not solved the issue for me.  I have tried going through the settings to set up end points for [restricted networks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/security/how-to-connect-to-workspace-from-restricted-network) without joy.

This [blog](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-architecture-blog/understanding-azure-synapse-private-endpoints/ba-p/2281463) on end points was my starting point but I don't see much on here about turning off Public access.

Other than this issue everything else seems OK. I have proven that I cannot connect to Azure SQL without first adding an end point - this is directly on Synapse and although I approve in in the Private Link Center it only appears in Synapse (similarly for Key Vault) so all of this works but for me connecting from a private end point.

Any help very welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We had a couple of problems.

1. The A Records contained within our Private DNS zones were missing for some reason.  I think this was because we had created and recreated the Private endpoints more than once and in the clean up process this had impacted the record sets.
2. Our Private DNS zones did not have the correct Virtual link records.

Now these have been resolved and a Virtual Machine resides in our Customer VNET we are able to connect.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same error. Turned out we had to be added as Synapse Administrators on the required workspace

[image]